# simulation time is not same during the simulation in NAM and size of packet difference

Tags: networking, adhoc, ns2

I have the TCL file and each time modify some parts of codes face different simulation time  run in NAM, I need it be 1000 second but the simulation seems less than this time, how should I do it? Also if I choose 128 for size of packet is better or not? what is difference if I have bigger size of packet?

```
# Define options

set val(chan)       Channel/WirelessChannel ;#Channel Type

set val(prop)       Propagation/TwoRayGround ;# radio-propagation model

set val(netif)      Phy/WirelessPhy     ;# network interface type

set val(mac)        Mac/802_11      ;# MAC type

set val(ifq)        Queue/DropTail/PriQueue ;# interface queue type

set val(ll)         LL          ;# link layer type

set val(ant)        Antenna/OmniAntenna     ;# antenna model

set val(ifqlen)     150             ;# max packet in ifq

set val(nn)         150             ;# total number of nodes

set val(att)        10

set flows       4           ;# No.of Flows  

set val(speed)          9

set val(nn2)    [expr $val(nn) - $val(att)] 

set val(rp)         DSR         ;# routing protocol

set val(x)      800         ;# X dimension of topography

set val(y)      800         ;# Y dimension of topography

set val(cstop)      451             ;# time of connections end

set val(stop)       50          ;# time of simulation end

set val(engmodel)       EnergyModel            ;# Energy type model

set val(initeng)        8.5                ;# Initial energy in Joules

set val(txPower)        0.660;             ;# Initial transmit power

set val(rxPower)        0.395;             ;# Initial receive power

set val(idlePower)      0.035;             ;# Initial idle power

set val(cp)         "../scen/scen-750x750-N150-S$val(speed)"

set val(cc)         "../scen/CBR-$flows-expo"

set psize       512

set rate        50


# Initialize Global Variables

set ns_ [new Simulator]

#$ns_ use-newtrace

set tracefd [open out.tr w]

$ns_ trace-all $tracefd

set namtrace [open out.nam w]

$ns_ namtrace-all-wireless $namtrace $val(x) $val(y)


# configure node, please note the change below.

$ns_ node-config -adhocRouting $val(rp) \

    -llType $val(ll) \

    -macType $val(mac) \

    -ifqType $val(ifq) \

    -ifqLen $val(ifqlen) \

    -antType $val(ant) \

    -propType $val(prop) \

    -phyType $val(netif) \

    -topoInstance $topo \

    #-energyModel $val(engmodel) \

    #-initialEnergy $val(initeng) \

        #-txPower $val(txPower) \

        #-rxPower $val(rxPower) \

    #-idlePower $val(idlePower) \

    -agentTrace ON \

    -routerTrace ON \

    -macTrace OFF \

    -movementTrace ON \

    -channel $chan_1_



puts "Loading random connection pattern..."

set god_ [God instance]

source $val(cp)

source $val(cc)




# Tell all nodes when the simulation ends

for {set i 0} {$i < $val(nn) } {incr i} {

    $ns_ at $val(stop).000000001 "$node_($i) reset";

}



# Ending nam and simulation

$ns_ at $val(stop) "finish"

$ns_ at $val(stop).0 "$ns_ trace-annotate \"Simulation has ended\""

$ns_ at $val(stop).00000001 "puts \"NS EXITING...\" ; $ns_ halt"



proc finish {} {

    global ns_ tracefd namtrace

    $ns_ flush-trace

    close $tracefd

    close $namtrace

    # exec nam out.nam &

    exec ./find1.bin

    exit 0

}

puts "Starting Simulation..."

$ns_ run
```

Answer (score 0):

»» I need it be 1000 second ... ««

The file you show in your post has stop = 50.

And `stop´ is the maximum time.

When a simulation has e.g. 5 seconds of "work" in the files :

Will stop after 5 seconds, no matter how long time you set.

..............

set val(stop) 50  ;# stop is the time to stop the simulation, if it is still running.

..............

Comment: I know it set 50, but it works well before I change the number of nodes to 150. I wonder what is happening?